# I am trying to save different ID per tab and getting different errors and I don't know the cause

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms, viewstate

I am trying to save information on ViewState to have different ID per tab but I am getting this error and can't figure out what to be the cause of it for a few days now.
When I try to run it without debugging
Compiler Error Message: CS1026:) expected.

And on the other hand when I do try to debug it is giving me another error
CS1525 Invalid expression term ';'.
please could anyone help me figure out what may be the cause this error?

```
var makat;
window.onload = () => {
<% 
if(ViewState["IsPostBack"] != null && ViewState["IsPostBack"].ToString() != "true") 
{
ViewState["IsPostBack"] = "true";
ViewState["makat"] = %> sessionStorage.getItem("latestMakat") <% ;
} %>

makat = <%=ViewState["makat"].ToString();
%> }
```

Comment: Why are you using WebForms in 2022? And why are you using ViewState _at all_?

Comment: `ViewState["IsPostBack"] = "true";` <-- This won't do what you want it to do.

Comment: `ViewState["IsPostBack"].ToString() != "true"` <-- _\*sigh\*_, no this is _not_ how to correctly deal with boxed boolean values (fwiw `true.ToString()` is `"True"`, not `"true"`).

Comment: I'm working on old platforms and we are using here webforms..  This page is used to upload files and when a form is submitted it reloads the page, therefor I need to save the ID of which the file is related to. But the user can have few tabs open for different id's.. Therefor I thought sessionStorage isn't the correct solution.. And someone adviced me to use ViewState and on first load take value from session then take value from the viewstate per the tab..